# Listbox limits number of rows

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, listbox

I have an application that loops through items in a listbox.

The trouble is the list box is only holding about 1300 lines of data and I need to loop through more like 3000.

What are my options, other than using a listbox control.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 Dim count As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
    For n As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim l_text As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(n))

        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.myurl.com/data.feed?text=" & l_text & "")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        Select Case response.StatusCode

            Case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK

                Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
                Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

                document.LoadXml(contents)

                Dim ds As DataSet
                ds = New DataSet()
                ds.ReadXml(New XmlNodeReader(document))

                If ds.Tables.Count <= 4 Then

                    'Do Nothing

                Else

                 'Do Something
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"What are my options, other than using a listbox control."_ If the user doesn't need to see the items in the list (for instance, to select one) use an actual [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). It is unlikely that anyone is going to be scrolling through 3000 items to find anything.

Comment: Thanks, simple - but effective :)